# Swift 2.0 REPL shows error before "Welcome to Apple Swift" message

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, swift2

I have installed both xcode 6.3 and xcode beta 7.0 on my mac. I want to use swift 2.0 REPL in my terminal so I ran the command below to switch to swift 2.0 in the REPL:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

The above command worked and now I can access swift 2.0 in terminal REPL but now I get a warning before the REPL shows. The warning shown is:

```
error: libarclite_macosx.a(arclite.o) failed to load objfile for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a
```

How to fix this error message?

Comment: Same here. Most probably a bug, you should file a report at Apple.

Comment: It’s beta software – you should expect bugs.